# 'get off of me' or 'get off me'. what is the difference?

Tags: grammar

I saw someone in a movie say, 
I don't know the difference between "You get him off of me."and"You get him off me."
Please, tell me the difference.

Comment: [You don't listen, do you?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/266679/is-the-sentence-i-want-to-take-a-rest-wrong#comment587092_266679)

Answer (score 0):

In average speech there is no difference, the only difference between the two phrases is that "off of" is technically grammatically incorrect, however this is only a minor difference and it is only a technical difference.

You can use either for all the same situations.